# result of php array is [value][value], how can i get the result like [value,value]

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

i have a json result from php row is like ["value"]["value"]

i have try to use implode function, but it was get to result "value""value"

```sql
|id_kategori|created_at         |
---------------------------------
|3          |2019-10-21 00:00:00|
|3          |2019-10-23 00:00:00|
|2          |2019-10-23 00:00:00|
```

i need that table will show how many count in a day by date in an array, not a rows like in date 23 it will show `"2"` and date 21 will show `"1"`, but in array like `[2,1]` not `[2][1]` result

```php
foreach ($samples as $jml){
$cek = $this->db->query("SELECT count(*) AS jumlah FROM tb_berita WHERE LEFT(created_at,10) IN ('$jml->tgl2')")->result();
  $names2 = array_column($cek, 'jumlah');
  echo $data['total'] = json_encode($names2);
        }
```

and the result is

```
["2"]["1"]
```

i need the final result show [value,value] not like [value][value].
which mean is result

```
["2","1"]
```

Comment: can you please show us what we get in `$names2`

Comment: $names2 will show as json_encode and the result is ["2"]["1"], but i need it result would be ["2","1"]

Comment: I want to know what `$names2 = array_column($cek, 'jumlah')` gives ? not the json encode

Answer (score 0):

[solved]
i change the script into

```php
$grafik = $this->db->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') AS tgl , COUNT(*) AS jumlah FROM tb_berita GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY tgl DESC")->result();

        $names = array_column($grafik, 'tgl');
        $data['tgl'] = json_encode($names);

        $names2 = array_column($grafik, 'jumlah');
        $data['total'] = json_encode($names2);
```

so i can have date and row total from table in one situation.

```sql
|date         |count(*)  |
--------------------------
|2019-10-23   |2         |
|2019-10-21   |1         |
```

Comment: Good news. Still dont know quite what you solved but great.